# Refreshing static content with Boot

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, spring-boot

I use spring boot with gradle and netbeans.

A part of my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
  runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
}
```

In my resources folder I have, static folder who contain

css (folder)
js (folder)
html

TomcatEmbedded is started autommatically by the script.

When I modified a css, js or html, change is not took in consideration.
I need to stop gradle script and run it again.

Is there a setup to do to be able to hotswap the code?

Comment: I don't have experience with netbeans but there isn't much to it on eclipse. /src/main/resources/static/* is re-loadable for me. Any chance you have some kind of cache control headers being set on the resources and the browser isn't fetching?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the gradle "bootRun" task, not "run". bootRun will allow the reloading.